# How do I integrate SAML into my Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, single-sign-on, saml

I have a rails app that is currently an affiliate site with my customer's SSO Identity Provider.  Currently it uses the CA SiteMinder Affiliate Agent, which is an apache module.  The underlying SSO architecture is abstracted away and my Rails app only has to parse and HTTP Header to receive the values from my customer's Identity Server.  I now have to convert my site away from the SiteMinder Apache Module and use SAML.  Does anyone have experience with how this should be implemented?  Is there an Apache Module that can continue the abstraction I'm used to now, or will my Rails application be responsible for parsing the SAML assertions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team implemented the SAML protocol in Ruby and it worked well.  The were some minor hiccups in using some libraries to compute hash values, but it worked.  I'm not sure if there is a better plug and play solution by now, but understanding the SAML authentication process and implementing our part only took a few days.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSAML is a library - it's not really a replacement for Site Minder. Perhaps you're thinking of [OpenSSO](https://opensso.dev.java.net/). It is an open source product very similar to Site Minder that supports SAML and Apache.